# Module `Html` does not expose `beginnerProgram`

Tags: elm

I'm trying to `import Html exposing (beginnerProgram)`, as it is shown [there](http://elm-lang.org/examples/buttons) and [there](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html#beginnerProgram), but the compiler doesn't agree : "Module `Html` does not expose `beginnerProgram`".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make sure your `elm-package.json` has `"elm-lang/html": "2.0.0 <= v < 3.0.0"`?

Comment: What version of Elm are you on? 0.18 uses `Html.beginnerProgram` and `Html.program`, while the previous version used `Html.App.beginnerProgram` and `Html.App.program`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The above answer is for older versions of ELM. An updated answer is below.

#### Updated For Elm 0.19:

**Add import statement:**

```
import Browser exposing (sandbox)
```

**Use sandbox:** Note that we are *not* using `Never` - as in old code samples - we are using `()` instead:

```
main : Program () Model Msg
main = Browser.sandbox
       { init = initialModel
       , view = view
       , update = update
       }
```

Works beautifully: and I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Solved by importing from `Html.App` instead of `Html`.

Comment: So this means that you are not using the latest version of Elm. If you want to continue seeking for advice on SO or other communities, you should first upgrade to the latest version (at the moment it is 0.18).